# Desktop Environment crashes in Ubuntu mate 16.10 how to fix this

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am new to Linux, I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.4 to 16.10, after upgradations the Desktop is not working properly

1. I am not able to open change Desktop Background
2. I am not able to add advanced mate menu to the Panel
3. If the desktop gets locked, there is no way I can unlock it as the screen saver does not go away even after I pressing buttons on keyboard
4. I am frequently getting message that " ubuntu mate 16.10 is experiencing an internal error please report"

I searched for solution but yet I am clueless about what can be done about it

Please Help

Thank You

Comment: Just a suggestion, if its possible, try sticking with LTS version `16.04` . They are better and more stable non LTS `16.10`

Comment: I feel the same now is there anyway where I can roll back to 16.4 from 16.10